# Are there any standard design practices for RESTful architectures?

Tags: rest

One of the downsides of being self-taught is that you're forever reinventing the wheel.

I'm working more and more on RESTful architectures and, as a result, need to define resources and how one can interact with them.

Are there any standard (and effective) design methods or templates that help enumerate the various HTTP verbs and potential responses for resources to help ensure that all of the permutations are covered?

Even something as basic as:

```
+----------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Resource Name: |                                             |
+----------------+---------------------------------------------+
|                      HTTP METHODS                            |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Method     |  Supported                                      |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| GET        |     X                                           |
| PUT        |     X                                           |
| POST       |                                                 |
| DELETE     |                                                 |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
|                        RESPONSES                             |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GET                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Details of valid and necessary parameters for GETs and the   |
| possible responses...                                        |
| ...                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Sure... I could roll my own, but wondering if there are any broadly recognised methodologies out there that I could adopt.

Comment: Your ascii-art diagram reminds me of [jax-doclets](http://www.lunatech-labs.com/open-source/jax-doclets) which (if you're using Java / JAX-RS) auto-generates human-readable documentation for the RESTful API, based on the Javadoc of the annotated methods.

Comment: Anyone coming to this today may want to check out things like http://swagger.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I posted this, I have recently discovered a number of API designers. One of these ([Mulesoft's Anypoint Platform](http://www.mulesoft.com/platform/enterprise-integration)) uses a language called [RAML](http://raml.org/) (RESTful API Modelling Language).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [Web Application Description Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language). Some REST frameworks can even generate the description for you. I like [Apache Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) very much (if you can accept Java for implementation).

Answer (score 1):

RestMS.org contains a standard for designing Restful APIs.

It shouldn't be treated as gospel, but you will learn a lot by reading through the single page RestTL (Restful Transport Layer) definition.

http://www.restms.org/spec:1

Answer (score 0):

The most widely-accepted and understood method is to make your RESTful messages self-descriptive:

```
GET /foo HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT
...

{"description": "A foo. PUT a new representation to overwrite this one.", ...}
```

`/foo` is the "Resource Name", the "Allow" header is the list of "HTTP METHODS", and the response body delineates the "RESPONSES" information, either in prose or as a set of controls (like an HTML form).

To ensure all the permutations are covered, write tests.

Comment: Did you mean OPTIONS /foo   ?

Comment: That seems a reasonable way to report the verbs to which a resource reports, but I was talking more about the design of resources as opposed to the implementation of them, or how the specification might be made available to others.

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard methods for designing REST APIs, as far as I know. And people often spend too much time discussing whether they should use PUT or POST for a particular method. I believe the most important is to keep it simple, be consistent with the use of verbs and formats, and document it extremely well.

I don't think you should try to cover all the permutations of HTTP verbs and resources, because most probably [you ain't gonna need it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) .

If you are looking for a template, have a look at the [REST API guidelines from Atlassian](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/REST/Atlassian+REST+API+Design+Guidelines+version+1). 
In my experience a wiki works much better than any kind of tool that auto-generates documentation from the code.

Comment: The semantics of `PUT` and `POST` are pretty well defined, and I really think you should stick with it. I have implemented several REST style interfaces for various applications, and all users were happy I did. IMHO it's *very important* to keep `GET` idempotent, as the bare minimum.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way to describe the design of a RESTful Application/API because REST is an architectural principle+method and not a well defined framework or design pattern.

You can use any tool to describe your resources and their interactions (from a simple spreadsheet to an UML-diagram if you want). Anything will work as far as you could read 3 major elements on the resulting document:

1. The resources your application will provide
2. The methods each resources will accept
3. The links beetween each resources

From this point, you will be able to create the internal URL scheme of your application, create the public URL, etc ...